# Objdump / linker map file symbol checksums

Tags: gcc, linker, symbols

How can I generate a map file or symbol list with checksums for all symbols that have data? At the very least stuff in the data section and the text section.

I want this in order to be able to compare what parts of project have changed between versions. I want a list of things that have actually changed in the final executable and so getting a list of symbols with not just length but the checksum of the contents as well would be optimal.

Comment: I don't think there is a built-in option for this in either tool (also look at 'nm'). If you don't find such an option you're looking at creating a customised variant of the tool, they are all open source after all...